# How do I get the turtles position in PythonTurtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

If I made some random movements.
How can I get the position of the turtle to go back there?

I tried using some commands like
pos()
turtle.pos()
But it never said the x and y coordinate
I use the turtle libary
So I type in from turtle import*

Comment: store the positions in memory if you want to retrace the movements...

Comment: I suggest sharing your code and a bit of context about what you're trying to accomplish that requires saving the position. I don't quite follow what you're suggesting with "But it never said the x and y coordinate" and `from turtle import *` (not a good idea, it pollutes the global namespace). Another approach in addition to the current answer is to use [undo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.undo), useful for certain situations.

Comment: So, Im trying to do a christmas tree and for the leave Im trying to do a curvature. I want the position at the top of the tree because (Im to lazy to reverse the movements) to do the other side, so Im just typing: pos() ate the point where I want to get the position but it never outputs the x and y coordinate. And what is a global namespace? Thank you for triyng to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code for getting the coordinates of the turtle:

```
x = turtle.xcor() #For x-coordinate
y = turtle.ycor() #For y-coordinate
```

You can store the value in some variables(like `x` and `y`).

Alternatively, if you want to get the coordinates of turtle in the form of a vector, the you can use the `.pos()` method. Example code:

```
pos = turtle.pos() #This returns a 2d vector in the form of (x,y)
```

To make the turtle go to a certain position, you can use the `.goto()` method. Example code:

```
x = turtle.xcor()
y = turtle.ycor()

turtle.forward(100)
turtle.goto(x,y)
```